# .htaccess - after redirect from non-www to www, removed .php file extension appears

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect from non-www to www url. I have allready done removing .php file extension from files and forced trailing slash, but now when I do redirect from non-www to www, next happens.

1. When visiting urls with www, everything works OK, extension is removed and trailing slash is added.
2. When redirecting from mysite.com everything works fine and it redirects to www.mysite.com
3. BUT when I try to visit url

> mysite.com/example-page/

it redirects me to

> www.mysite.com/example-page.php/

How to remove .php from example-page.php?

Current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: have you tried reversing the order of the rules? btw, hope you dont have any subdomains, because theyll all point to the main site with that rule.

Comment: I have tried reversing the order, but problem is still present. Now I can see that one subdomen is redirected too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: This .htaccess code works great! Thank you. Now I need to take a look what I did wrong and analyze your code. Thanks again. EDIT: But, now I can't access subdomain.

Comment: ok edited, try it now. Make sure to test in a different browser.